# Не включается Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: raspberry-pi

У меня плата Raspberry Pi Zero W, вчера создал загрузочную флешку, вставил, подсоединил питание, засветился светодиод, но подключить монитор возможности не было. Сегодня проделал ту же операцию с той самой флешкой, но теперь при подсоединении питания светодиод не горит, плата быстро греется, при подключении монитора через HDMI пишет, что нет сигнала. Что могло произойти за эту ночь, плата была выключена, и с чем может быть связана эта проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Перепиши флешку, или лучше замени. Бывает помогает. Монитор подключать до включения. Не знаю как на этой модели с какими прошивками но бывает не продетектит хдмай и пускает вывод на аналоговый видео-выход.